# ScriptIgnore causes other attributes e.g StringLength are being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, scriptignore

I have some classes inheriting from a Base class.

```
public abstract class Test {    
[StringLength(16)]
public string Test {get; set;}
}
```

Above code creates a migration with maxLength is **16**.

```
AddColumn("dbo.Test", "Test", c => c.String(maxLength: 16, unicode: false));
```

So far everything is okay.

However, when I add `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute for Test property,

```
public abstract class Test {    
[StringLength(16)]
[ScriptIgnore]
public string Test {get; set;}
}
```

then it creates below migration, with maxLength is **8000**:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Test", "Test", c => c.String(maxLength: 8000, unicode: false));
```

It seems to me that `[ScriptIgnore]` is overriding all other attributes, which is bizarre.

When I create an empty MVC project, I cannot duplicate the issue. I believe that something is wrong with my project. What can it be?

Comment: Since the problem only happens on your project can you share the actual code with us?

Comment: What part of project you want me to share? As it's a commercial product I cannot share the whole project.

Comment: The model, and Configuration.cs, you can obfuscate product names in namespaces and such

Comment: @LiefdeWen here is the link: http://collabedit.com/uuj6h You may need to type something as a username before seeing the codes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happens internally to make this happen but I can suggest a good fix.

## Use DTO's

Create a class of `Test` that is specifically made to be used as a data transfer object. On this class you can remove properties, add properties without having to do the `[NotMapped]` attribute and add `[ScriptIgnore]` and have it work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That's obviously what I need to do... in long term and it's in my todo list. But the project wasn't structured for DTO's at the beginning, and the problem isn't the non-existing DTO's. So I need to solve the problem rather than using another way to ignore it.